# Is Retention Policy Depends on Crawling settings

Tags: crawling, retention

Is Retention Policy Depends on Crawling settings, Currently I am working on SharePoint 2016 in that I have 1 document library ,for this document library I created Retention Policy to move the document to the recycle bin. I checked many times that is am I correctly configured the Retention Policy and also followed the steps in Support office site, But still retention policy is not working.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not depending upon the search, rather their are two timer job which are responsible for this.

- Information Management Policy
- Expiration Policy

So make sure both jobs are enable and running, Both are schedule to run weekly. You can run it manually but make sure Information management Policy will run 1st.

Answer (score 0):

No it has nothing to do with search,

In addition to being able to specify policies for content types, you can also specify policies for libraries / folders. Policies set at this level override policies set at the content type level.

For more information please go through the following links they specify the retention policies set for lists and libraries,

https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/sharepoint-retention-policies/